# Play mp3 using JavaScript and swf

Tags: javascript, flash, mp3

Is there a Flash MP3 player that would allow me to do following to pass URL to mp3 file and get it automatically played. To help out with answer - here is detailed code that describes what I would like to do:

```
<object id="mp3PlayerSwf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="mp3Player.swf">
 <param name="movie" value="mp3Player.swf">
</object>

<input type="button" id="soundPlay1" value="Sound Play 1" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function eventHandler1(sender) {
        var mp3Player = document.getElementById("mp3PlayerSwf");
        mp3Player.playSound("http://myUrl.com/my.mp3");
    }

    var soundPlay1 = document.getElementById('soundPlay1');
    if (soundPlay1.addEventListener) {
        soundPlay1.addEventListener('click', eventHandler1, false);
    }
    // IE
    else if (soundPlay1.attachEvent) {
        soundPlay1.attachEvent('onclick', eventHandler1);
    }
</script>
```

Constraint is that I can't use libraries that have JavaScript initialization - like for example SoundManager2 - http://www.schillmania.com/content/projects/soundmanager2/

Thanks for any help!

Comment: can't you create a Flash-movie yourself? Just use ExternalInterface to listen to the JS, and attach the MP3 file to a Sound-object..

Comment: I can't because I don't have Macromedia tools installed on my computer...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try dewplayer: http://www.alsacreations.fr/dewplayer-en

You can use it like this (sample code taken from the link):

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="dewplayer.swf" width="200" height="20" id="dewplayer" name="dewplayer">
<param name="movie" value="dewplayer.swf" />
<param name="flashvars" value="mp3=test.mp3" />
<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
</object>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response... I think this is closest I'll get.

I just don't understand why every single developer needs to turn their simple play button in _full_blown_oh_it_has_all_these_stupid_options_that_show_how_great_programmer_I_am_ fiasco...

Answer (score 2):

Another player would be http://musicplayer.sourceforge.net